# facebook logout not working

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-php-sdk, logout

I have downloaded recent version of facebook php sdk. I am able to use fb login on my website. But logout is not working. The script remembers the user data. How to correct this problem ? Following is the code I am using.

```
<?php
require '../src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxx',
 'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
 }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}


?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title>php-sdk</title>
<style>
  body {
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  h1 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3b5998;
  }
  h1 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>php-sdk</h1>

 <?php if ($user): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
 <?php else: ?>
  <div>
    Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
    <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
  </div>
 <?php endif ?>

<h3>PHP Session</h3>
<pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

<?php if ($user): ?>
  <h3>You</h3>
  <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

  <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
  <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
<?php else: ?>
  <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
<?php endif ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the app from your Facebook account then retry.
This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put array('next') to `$logoutUrl`
2. Use `session_destroy();`

   `$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => 'url_you_are_redirecting_user_to')); 
   session_destroy();`

Take a notice, that redirecting link should be  in the same domain scope as the all Facebook application. Otherwise you will be redirected to Facebook home page.